# How to sanitze the row data in the slick-grid?

Tags: angularjs, slickgrid, sanitization, ng-bind-html, html-sanitizing

We are using slick-grid to show the data in our application in angularJS, We have data coming from the backend may contain `<,>` which is sending it as '`&lt;&gt;`'. this needs to be sanitized in slick grid because I cannot do it in controller due the data size we have. So how do we make show `&lt;&gt;` as <> using in slick grid? Is there any ways to do?
[image]

Normally in other places if I use `ng-bind-html=value` will make the `&lt;&gt;` to <> in span or div. Not able to do it in slick-grid data rows.

Answer (score 0):

you can do anything you want with a Custom Formatter, you can unescape it in there, but by default a formatter takes html string so just declaring a formatter and returning the value should fix your issue.

```js
this.columnDefinitions = [
  { id: 'test', field: 'test', formatter: (row, cell, value) => value, },
];
```

By the way, I don't think you meant Sanitize because that is another concept (typically sanitize is used for removing possible script tag that could open security holes), in your case I think you meant  unescape or unencode the html special characters as regular html. There's currently no sanitization in SlickGrid of Custom Formatter, so please be aware of that too... Actually that last sentence is no longer true, I created a [Pull Request](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/pull/652) that was merged and release to add basic sanitization to limit XSS attacks.